# Tables are not compiling using IEEEtran class

Tags: tables, ieeetran

I'm writing a paper using the `IEEEtran` class (conference mode) and the compiler even get stuck for the simple example table one can find in the [manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran).

Here is the almost minimal example:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

%Hello World!
\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{A Simple Example Table}
\label{table_example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c||c}
\hline
\bfseries First & \bfseries Next\\
\hline\hline
1.0 & 2.0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Did anybody had similar problems and remember how to solve it?

Sorry for all the packages, I'm not able to filter which ones are exactly needed for solving this issue.

Comment: Do you need [`arydshln`](http://ctan.org/pkg/arydshln)? If not, remove and try again.

Comment: For finding what package, if any, is to blame, you can do a binary search. Remove (or comment out) half of them and see if the error persists. If it does, remove half of the remaining ones, else put them back and remove the other half. Keep on that way, and you should find the package in about $\log_2 n$ steps if there were $n$ packages to begin with. It gets more complicated, of course, if two or more packages must all be included to produce the error. But a similar principle should be helpful.

Comment: I'd remove first `mdwtab`, which is a very old and unsupported package. Don't load `mdwmath` either.

Comment: Thanks to all! For future problems I summed up your suggestion in an answer, as the solution was to remove a preset package, which comes with the template. Which is not the first coming in mind.

Comment: @egreg: that helped! If you want to post it as an answer, I'll delete mine and accept yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in bad interaction between `arydshln` and `mdwtab`. Note that the last available version of `mdwtab` is dated 1998-04-28: it's old and unsupported.

Another problem is that templates one finds on the net are often replete with calls to old packages and bad practices.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

%Hello World!
\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{A Simple Example Table}
\label{table_example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c||c}
\hline
\bfseries First & \bfseries Next\\
\hline\hline
1.0 & 2.0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Notes.

1. `\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500` is a completely useless setting, because `amsmath` will not break pages in the middle of an alignment and you won't be using `eqnarray`.
2. The package `caption` is incompatible with the `IEEEtran` class.
3. The `pdftex` option should not be set for `graphicx`.

Comment: thanks for extensive answer, quite annoying that I'm forced to use the template and it's than not maintained properly and not working.